# Capture or warn of redirect before it occurs

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

I'm using Chrome and Firefox \w firebug. I need to track down what I believe is some JavaScript that's causing certain pages to redirect to itself. How can I stop the redirect so that I can tell what is causing it and where ie HEADER or windows.location.

Comment: Use HTTPFox to capture the headers of each request. That'd let you see if it's a PHP header() call doing the redirect. Otherwise, set a breakpoint on any place in your JS that has window.location and the like.

Comment: Turn off firebug and see if you still have the problem. Firebug is known to load the page once more in the background.

Comment: Replace the windows.location with console.log('here')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TamperData](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) plugin for Firefox.